# Enable docker for gitlab ci community edition

Tags: docker, sbt, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am having difficulties with enabling docker for build job. This is how gitlab ci config file looks like:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build

build:
  image: java:8
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com/...
    - sbt server/docker:publish
```

And here is the output from job:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.3.2 (0323456)
Using Docker executor with image java:8 ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image java:8 ...
Running on runner-30dcea4b-project-1408237-concurrent-0 via runner-30dcea4b-machine-1470340415-c2bbfc45-digital-ocean-4gb...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/.../...'...
Checking out 9ba87ff0 as master...
$ docker info
/bin/bash: line 42: docker: command not found

ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Any clues why docker is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker info` command is running inside `java:8` based container which will not have docker installed/available in it.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Is it possible to have a stage with sbt and docker available at the same time?

Comment: IMO, unless you always need docker latest image, install java and sbt under a container of docker:latest and commit a new image out of it. Use the image as the source point in your CI script. Then you can skip calling for another image (java:8) under build too.

Answer (score 2):

After few days of struggling, I came up with following setup:

```
image: gitlab/dind

stages:
  - test
  - build

before_script:
 - echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
 - apt-get update
 - apt-get install -y curl
 - apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
 - add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
 - apt-get update
 - apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
 - rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 - rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
 - apt-get update -yqq
 - apt-get install apt-transport-https -yqq
 - echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
 - apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
 - apt-get update -yqq
 - apt-get install sbt -yqq
 - sbt sbt-version

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - sbt scalastyle && sbt test:scalastyle
    - sbt clean coverage test coverageReport

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com/...
    - sbt server/docker:publish
```

It has docker (mind `gitlab/dind` image), java and sbt. Now I can push to gitlab registry from `sbt docker` plugin.